# How do I draw a violin plot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, data-visualization, boxplot

Can I use `ggplot2` to produce a violin plot? Perhaps using some variation of `geom_boxplot()`?

Comment: Can you mark @Ben's as the accepted answer, since it is now the preferred method?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Version 0.9.0 includes the `geom_violin`:  http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_violin.html

Answer (score 5):

A quick googling returns [this site](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-3/), which uses geom_ribbon to draw violin plots for Figure 3.14.

**Note to anyone catching up**

As @Ben points out below, geom_violin() is now the preferred method for producing violin plots in ggplot2.

Comment: Note that this works with corrections: http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/91d6043a7e103444?pli=1 .  Thanks to @RomanLuštrik for this.